# What is the Rails way to do this - shared controllers/views or separate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 types of users in an app I have just picked up that I need to enhance.

`Admins`, *who can do everything*

`RoomAdmins`, *who can only manage anything to do with their Room - like adding
Parents, who belong to the Room.*

For example, `RoomAdmins` when they sign up, can CRUD `Parents` for their room (for which there is already a `RoomAdmin/ParentsController`).

Now I need to give `Admins` the ability to manage `Parents`. So should I create an `Admin/ParentsController` and create a set of views specific to those use cases?

Or is the 'Rails' convention to move the `RoomAdmin/ParentsController` to `app/controllers` and have both `RoomAdmins` and `Admins` share that controller? This will make that controller far more complex (and the views also).

Bear in mind that the views will be slightly different for each Admin type, and the logic in each action will have minor differences depending on where we route to after each action based on whether it is an Admin or a RoomAdmin acting on that parent.

So which option is the Rails convention?

**A - separate controllers, separate views**

**B - one controller, one set of views, more complex logic to handle the differences?**

**EDIT**

There is added complexity I forgot here, which is the controller inheritance chain, since both types of users have a different main layout and sign-in process:

All controllers dealing with Rooms currently inherit from `RoomAdminsController`.

All controllers dealing with Admin functionality inherit from `AdminController`.

So `RoomAdmin/ParentsController` currently inherits from `RoomAdminsController`.

If I move it, which one does it then inherit from? Agh!

Comment: Are you implementing the logic for users yourself? Or using something like Devise?

Comment: Move ParentsController to app/controller & create different actions as per the requirement .Avoid duplicate code as per the DRY principal.

Comment: I don't think there is a convention for this.  I would have one admin area and use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to handle the logic, specifying different roles for users and granting them access to different actions.

Comment: @JamesWatling Devise is creating both Admins and PodAdmins

Comment: @j-dexx that would entail a re-write of about 50% of the application. See my edit - the entire app has been written with a totally separate structure for the two types of users :(

Comment: @rmcsharry if you wanted one controller and view, can you not push `current_admin` and `current_room_admin` methods into application controller and inherit from that?  Or do both base admin controllers have a `current_admin` type method with the same name?

Comment: @j-dexx there is a type method in the users (ie admins) table, so you can do current_admin.type to find out which is which.  But now I have looked through more of the code and I can see that the current architecture is doomed already. There are already separate controllers and views for other functions. I will have to re-write this to use cancan as you suggested. If you would like to make your comment an answer, I will mark is at the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments I think the correct solution is one controller:

> I think the solution is to move ParentsController to app/controller &
>   create different actions as per the requirement. Avoid duplicate code
>   as per the DRY principal.

from @Chakreshwar

> I don't think there is a convention for this. I would have one admin
>   area and use cancancan to handle the logic, specifying different roles
>   for users and granting them access to different actions.

from @j-dexx